# Why we have to use pooled sample proportion to calculate the pooled standard deviation of the difference?

Tags: statistical-significance, ab-test

The context can be found in [Hypothesis Test: Difference Between Proportions](https://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx)

It says there:
`Pooled sample proportion. Since the null hypothesis states that P1=P2, we use a pooled sample proportion (p) to compute the standard error of the sampling distribution.`

I am looking for an answer in a style  of statistical derivation.